# How to parse specific data from JSON request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm getting into coding, and I'm wondering how I'd go about retrieving the data for "tag_id": 4 specifically.

I know that to get the data for status, but how would I go about getting specific data if there are multiple entries?

```
r = requests.get('url.com', headers = user_agent).json()
event = (r['status'])

print(event)

//////////////////

{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "status_message": "blah blah blah",
  "pri_tag": [
      {
          "tag_id": 1,
          "name": "Tag1"
      },
      {
          "tag_id": 2,
          "name": "Tag2"
      },
      {
          "tag_id": 3,
          "name": "Tag3"
      },
      {
          "tag_id": 4,
          "name": "Tag4"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: print (event["pri_tag"][3]["tag_id"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop answer is sufficient, but this is a good chance to learn how to use list comprehensions, which are ubiquitous and "pythonic":

```
desired_tag_name = [tag["name"] for tag in event["pri_tag"] if tag["tag_id"] == 4]
```

List comprehensions are advantageous for readability (I know it may not seem so the first time you look at one) and because they tend to be much faster.

There is a bounty of documentation and blog posts out there to understand the syntax better, and I don't prefer any particular one over another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
tags = event["pri_tag"]
for tag in tags:
    if tag['tag_id']==4:
        print(tag['name'])
```

Output:

```
Tag4
```